# Cannot Create Testing Folders In Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a project where I have created both a Java and an Android library.

Within the Android library, a testing folder was created, see below:

[image]

However, I want to add testing in the main application module, not the Android library. The main application was code provided by someone else, and the testing folders were not added.

I originally tried copying and pasting the folders, but now I am seeing that has caused problems as my new testing folders are not indexing. In other words, I cannot access any outside classes, and the Android Studio / IntelliJ editor is not responding:

[image]

[image]

Full Source Code:https://github.com/troy21688/ud867

Comment: It should be `androidTest` instead of `androidEndpointTest`

Comment: I changed the name since there was already another test folder,  can I have multiple folders same name different modules?

Comment: Yes, you can have.

Comment: That's ok :) But you did understand why it should be `androidTest` and not `androidEndpointTest` right?

Comment: Somewhat, it sounds like that is how Android recognizes test classes. Can I name the Java class whatever I want?

Comment: Posted the answer, since can't put all that in comments :P

Comment: One more question - how do you create the "java" folder under androidTest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android gradle setup follows the standard maven folder structure, i.e, `src/main/java`, `src/test/java`, etc...

Your production code will go into `src/main/java`, 
Your JVM unit test code goes into `src/test/java`, 
Your tests that needs Android device goes into `src/androidTest/java`.

These are standard folder names. Gradle be default recognizes these folder names. If you need to provide your own folder names (you should try to avoid these), you need to add the below config in your `build.gradle`.

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        androidTest.java.srcDirs += "src/androidEndpointTest/java"
    }
}
```

Now, inside the `src/main/java` or `src/androidTest/java` you can create any `Java file` you want. But you cant have the same Java file with the same package inside both `src/main/java` and `src/androidTest/java`. For example, you can't have `src/main/java/com/example/SomeFile.java` and `src/androidTest/java/com/example/SomeFile/java`. This is because Gradle will merge these folders during running tests, and you can't have two files with same name in the same folder.